iPhone keyboard dissapear and appear again when switching between fields with onTapGesture(hideKeyboard)
I have this code in Swift (iOS 16+) and I have a login screen into my app, where the user needs to enter an email and password.
I also have a .onTapGesture method on the GeometryReader { ... } wrapping everything together. I want the user to be able to dismiss the keyboard when tapping away from the text field.
But when the user enters an email and then wants to enter a password, the keyboard disappear and then appears again. How can I do that so the keyboard stays open (same expecting result as without the onTapGesture).
Here is my code
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    
    private let hapticFeedbackService = HapticFeedbackService()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { screenGeometry in
            let screenHeight = screenGeometry.size.height
            
            ZStack {
                Color.black.background.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                
                VStack {
                    WelcomeTextView(welcomeText: "sign_in_to")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.top, screenHeight * 0.02)
                    
                    VStack {
                        InputField(
                            text: $email,
                            placeholder: "enter_email",
                            isSecure: false
                        )
                        .padding(.bottom, 15)
                        
                        InputField(
                            text: $password,
                            placeholder: "enter_password",
                            isSecure: true,
                            trailingIcon: Image("Lock")
                        )
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                        print("Button pressed")
                    }) {
                        Text(LocalizedStringKey("forgot_your_password"))
                            .font(.thinnerSmallTitle)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    
                    LargeButton(
                        text: "sign_in",
                        textColor: Color.black,
                        backgroundColor: Color.white
                    ) {
                        hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                        print("Button pressed")
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 40)
                    
                    Text(LocalizedStringKey("other_login_options"))
                        .font(.mediumText)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                    
                    HStack {
                        SSOButton(type: .Apple, action: {
                            hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                            print("Button pressed")
                        })
                        .padding(.trailing, 5)
                        
                        SSOButton(type: .Google, action: {
                            hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                            print("Button pressed")
                        })
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(LocalizedStringKey("dont_have_account"))
                            .font(.mediumText)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                            print("Button pressed")
                        }) {
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey("dont_have_account_sign_up"))
                                .font(.smallTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 25)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .paddedFrame(
                    screenSize: screenGeometry.size,
                    horizontalSizeClass: horizontalSizeClass
                )
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        .onTapGesture { self.hideKeyboard() }
    }
    
    private func hideKeyboard() {
        // UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true) - Deprecated
        
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(
            #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),
            to: nil,
            from: nil,
            for: nil
        )
    }
}

Thank you.

One another solution is like
on your ZStack
ZStack {
       Color.yellow.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).onTapGesture {
                        hideKeyboard()
                    }

And at the bottom no need to give tap geture to your entire ZStack
ZStack {
//Your code
 }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        .onTapGesture { self.hideKeyboard() }

            

It should work.

It works fine, thanks a lot!

You shouldn't put close keyboard action to the whole view. Because it will dismiss the keyboard when you click anywhere. And the reason its reappearing is textfield realizing its on edit mode after the keyboard dismisses.
struct MyView: View {    
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    
    private let hapticFeedbackService = HapticFeedbackService()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { screenGeometry in
            let screenHeight = screenGeometry.size.height
            
            ZStack {
                Color.black.background.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                .onTapGesture { self.hideKeyboard() }
                
                VStack {
                    WelcomeTextView(welcomeText: "sign_in_to")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.top, screenHeight * 0.02)
                        .onTapGesture { self.hideKeyboard() }
                    
                    VStack {
                        InputField(
                            text: $email,
                            placeholder: "enter_email",
                            isSecure: false
                        )
                        .padding(.bottom, 15)
                        
                        InputField(
                            text: $password,
                            placeholder: "enter_password",
                            isSecure: true,
                            trailingIcon: Image("Lock")
                        )
                    }
                    
                    Group {
                        Button(action: {
                            hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                            print("Button pressed")
                        }) {
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey("forgot_your_password"))
                                .font(.thinnerSmallTitle)
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                        .padding(.trailing, 5)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        
                        LargeButton(
                            text: "sign_in",
                            textColor: Color.black,
                            backgroundColor: Color.white
                        ) {
                            hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                            print("Button pressed")
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 40)
                        
                        Text(LocalizedStringKey("other_login_options"))
                            .font(.mediumText)
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                        
                        HStack {
                            SSOButton(type: .Apple, action: {
                                hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                                print("Button pressed")
                            })
                            .padding(.trailing, 5)
                            
                            SSOButton(type: .Google, action: {
                                hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                                print("Button pressed")
                            })
                            .padding(.leading, 5)
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey("dont_have_account"))
                                .font(.mediumText)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                hapticFeedbackService.triggerHapticFeedback()
                                print("Button pressed")
                            }) {
                                Text(LocalizedStringKey("dont_have_account_sign_up"))
                                    .font(.smallTitle)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture { self.hideKeyboard() }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .paddedFrame(
                    screenSize: screenGeometry.size,
                    horizontalSizeClass: horizontalSizeClass
                )
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }

    private func hideKeyboard() {
        // UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true) - Deprecated
        
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(
            #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),
            to: nil,
            from: nil,
            for: nil
        )
    }
}


Also works, thanks! When putting onTapGesture on the colour, it covers most of the areas, if I want to extend that to the image logo as well, then I can just add onTapGesture listener there as well.
